# Amazon S3 Lifecycle rules Prefix to move files to Glacier with certain naming convention

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup, amazon-glacier, duplicati

I am using `Duplicati` to store backup of important documents on `Glacier`, however the problem is with Lifecycle Rule Prefix. `Duplicati` guide says use prefix `duplicati-b*` to move dblock files to Glacier. Basically it asks to move all files beginning with duplicati-b, its been two days but the rule is not working :(

Is the wildcard '*' all right ? Is there any guide for all prefix types ? I'm only getting simple prefixes that are meant for subfolders. Any help ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5ncv.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQnQf.png

Comment: From [How to use Glacier to store backups](http://www.duplicati.com/news/howtouseglaciertostorebackups), your steps are correct, and the prefix `duplicati-b*` is fine. Could you check if there are any error logs in `Duplicati`?

Comment: Yup, followed all the steps. Wee I think logs won't help as the files are successfully uploaded to S3. Files just aren't moving to glacier. I've set lifecycle days to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used **duplicati-b** and the files moved over. :) It seems the prefix works as it is. No wildcard required.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the Duplicati docs are wrong, unless the object names actually include a literal `*` in them.  The prefix is a *prefix* ... not a wildcard string.

```
/path/to/wherever/in/bucket/is/duplicati-b
```

...would be a prefix matching `.../duplicati-b{anything or nothing at end of the key name}`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/lifecycle-configuration-bucket-no-versioning.html

If that's actually the root of something that looks like a folder, you could append a trailing `/` to the prefix.

Comment: I have folder (designator) called Michael and if I want to move all files within Michael folder along with Michael folder, Would  
/path/to/wherever/in/bucket/is/Michael/ 
create a folder(designator) in Glacier and move the files to that folder?
or
does it move the files to
/is/files from Michael folder?